# Как правильно написать: "Вавилонская башня"?

Tags: орфография, прописная-строчная

"Вавилонская Башня" — оба слова с прописной буквы или только "Вавилонская"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Словари рекомендуют башню - со строчной. "Вавилонская башня".
Но вопрос действительно несколько спорный. Строго говоря в библейском сюжете упоминается столб, а не башня, поэтому "башня" может рассматриваться как часть названия этого столба. В этом случае заглавная во втором слове вполне уместна.